# How to convert BGRA bytes to UIImage for saving?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, avcapturesession

I want to capture raw pixel data for manipulation using GPUImage framework. I capture the data like this:

```
 CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
     GLubyte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);
     size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);
     NSData *dataForRawBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImageBytes length:bytesPerRow * CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)];

     //raw values
     UInt32 *values = [dataForRawBytes bytes];//, cnt = [dataForRawBytes length]/sizeof(int);

     //test out dropbox upload here
     [self uploadDropbox:dataForRawBytes];
     //end of dropbox upload


     // Do whatever with your bytes
     //         [self processImages:dataForRawBytes];

     CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);     }];
```

I am using the following settings for camera:

```
 NSDictionary *settings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey,[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey, nil];
```

For testing purposes I want to save the image i capture to dropbox, to do that I need to save it to a tmp directory, how would i save dataForRawBytes? 
Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: 'UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self imageToBuffer:sampleBuffer]];'
I'm trying this but it gives me nil and I'm not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

So i was able to figure out how to gain a UIImage from the raw data, here is my modified code:

```
CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(imageSampleBuffer);
     CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);
     Byte *rawImageBytes = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cameraFrame);
     size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cameraFrame);
     size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cameraFrame);
     size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame);
     NSData *dataForRawBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:rawImageBytes length:bytesPerRow * CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cameraFrame)];
     // Do whatever with your bytes

     // create suitable color space
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

     //Create suitable context (suitable for camera output setting kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
     CGContextRef newContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawImageBytes, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

     CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(cameraFrame, 0);

     // release color space
     CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

     //Create a CGImageRef from the CVImageBufferRef
     CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(newContext);
     UIImage *FinalImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage];
     //is the image captured, now we can test saving it.
```

I needed to create properties such as colourspace and generate a CDContexyRef and work with that to finally get a UIImage, and when debugging I can properly see the image i captured.